# How to make hazelcast lose data when any node is down?

Tags: hazelcast

I have a shared Set in Hazelcast cluster. 2 nodes of Hazelcast add items to that set. I need the items added by node1 be deleted from that set when node1 is down. I want a set that stores items added only by active(running) hazelcast nodes. How can I achieve this?

I've tried the following:

```
Config config = new Config();
config.getSetConfig( "myset" ).setBackupCount( 0 ).setAsyncBackupCount( 0 );

HazelcastInstance hazelcast = com.hazelcast.core.Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance( config );
```

but it keeps the items added by node1 on node2's memory when node1 is down.

Answer (score 1):

I would keep the data in separate maps like `map_node1` and `map_node2` and when one of the members goes down, you can use a `MemberListener` on the other node to clean the corresponding map.